# Convert Time zonoffset value to varchar

Tags: sql-server, datetimeoffset, timezone-offset

Query:

```
DECLARE @TimeZoneOffset datetimeoffset
SELECT @TimeZoneOffset  = Time_Zone_Offset 
FROM OFFSET_TABLE WHERE Active=1
```

`Time_Zone_Offset` column contains value like -6:00 (only offset)

When I do `SELECT @TimeZoneOffset` it throws me an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I know I am doing something wrong. I may need to `CONVERT/CAST` but can't get o/p so far.

Any help

Answer (score 1):

To visualize what is happening here, try this:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR;
SET @x = 'abcdefghijklmnop';
SELECT @x;
```

Result:

```
----------
a
```

[You have silently lost data from your variable, because you didn't bother declaring a length for your `VARCHAR`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). In your case, I think you are ending up trying to use the string `-` somewhere, as opposed to the string `-6:00`.

I'm not sure how a simple `SELECT` yielded the error you mentioned; I suspect you are using it in some other context you haven't shown. But please try it again once your variable has been declared correctly.

Now I see why, your question wasn't correct - you said you were converting to `VARCHAR` but you weren't. This is not really unexpected, as `-6:00` is not a valid `DATETIMEOFFSET` value; there is expected to be **date** and **time** components as well, otherwise the data type would just be called `OFFSET`. A valid `DATETIMEOFFSET`, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx), is:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIMEOFFSET = '1998-09-20 7:45:50.71345 -05:00';
```

So perhaps you have some datetime value and you want to apply the offset, well you can use [`SWITCHOFFSET()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) for that. However `-6:00` is not a valid value; it needs to be in `[+/-]hh:mm` format (notice the leading 0 above, which seems to be missing from your sample data). So this would be valid:

```
DECLARE @datetime DATETIME = GETDATE(), @offset VARCHAR(6) = '-06:00';
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(@datetime, @offset);
```

You need to correct the data in your offsets table and you need to change the way you are using the output. Personally, I've found it easier to stay away from `DATETIMEOFFSET` and `SWITCHOFFSET()`, especially since they are not DST-aware. I've had much better luck using a calendar table for offsets, storing the offsets in minutes, and using `DATEADD` to switch between time zones. YMMV.

Comment: Yes correct I missed out. above truncates my data and display only "-"

Comment: Done, I forgot that by default varchar size is 1

Comment: Well, now you changed the question. Why do you think `-6:00` is a valid `DATETIMEOFFSET` value? Have you [looked at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)? What exactly are you trying to do with this? Switch some date/time value to 6 hours earlier or later? If so, ***what*** date/time value? Have you looked at [`SWITCHOFFSET()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx)?